# CNN in keras using theano as backend

Tags: python-2.7

I am very new to the keras. currently working with CNN in keras using theano as backend. I would like to train my network with own images( around 25000 images),which all are in same folder and test it. How could I do that? (please help me, i am not familiar with deep learning)

Comment: Read [this Keras blog post](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html) which illustrates how to train on images stored in folders.  Note that you will have to change your file hierarchy to indicate which data are for train and validation, and separate classes need to be assigned to different folders.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder dataset and then create two sub-folders train and test. Then inside Train if you wish create sub-folders with images labels (e.g. fish - holds all fish images, lion - holds lion images etc) and in test you can populate with some images. Finally train the model pointing to Dataset - > Train.